# Pass value from one field to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a 3 selection radio button options and also a number field, in case somebody wants to select more than radio buttons can offer. And i'm trying to pass a radio button value to the number field when radio value is changed.

Here is my html code for it

```
<!-- this is main add to cart form -->
<form>
    <!-- and this is secondary form for radio buttons, so, only one could be selected -->
    <form class="quanform">
        <div class="pricelinewrap">
            <div class="priceline">
                <div class="pricelinecellval">
                    <input type="radio" id="quanlineradio1" value="1" name="quanline" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pricelinewrap">
            <div class="priceline">
                <div class="pricelinecellval">
                    <input type="radio" id="quanlineradio2" value="2" name="quanline" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pricelinewrap">
            <div class="priceline">
                <div class="pricelinecellval">
                    <input type="radio" id="quanlineradio3" value="3" name="quanline" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
    <div class="newquanfield tablecell almiddle">
        <input type="number" min="1" size="2" class="quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="2" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my jquery code for it

```
$("form.quanform .pricelinewrap .priceline .pricelinecellval input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var quanval = $(this).val();
        $(this).parents().find(".newquanfield input[type=number]").val(quanval);  
    });
});
```

Nothing happens and there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies purely in your selector:
`$("form.quanform)` won't work, as your `<form class="quanform">` is wrapped inside another `<form>`, which is invalid markup; `<form>` [**cannot**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) be nested inside another `<form>`.

Because the 'desired' markup is invalid, it actually never gets added to the DOM. You can confirm this by viewing the source yourself with <kbd>CTRL + U</kbd> - `<form class="quanform">` doesn't exist. Thus, you cannot target it with jQuery.

You can validate your markup with the **[W3 Validation service](https://validator.w3.org)** to ensure that your HTML is indeed valid, ensuring that your jQuery selectors work the way you expect.

As for your current structure, you can omit the `.quanform` component, and simply use `$("form .pricelinewrap .priceline .pricelinecellval input[type=radio]")`, which will work based off of the **outer** `<form>` element (which does indeed exist in the DOM).

This can be seen working in the following example:

```js
$("form .pricelinewrap .priceline .pricelinecellval input[type=radio]").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    var quanval = $(this).val();
    $(this).parents().find(".newquanfield input[type=number]").val(quanval);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this is main add to cart form -->
<form>
  <!-- and this is secondary form for radio buttons, so, only one could be selected -->
  <form class="quanform">
    <div class="pricelinewrap">
      <div class="priceline">
        <div class="pricelinecellval">
          <input type="radio" id="quanlineradio1" value="1" name="quanline" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pricelinewrap">
      <div class="priceline">
        <div class="pricelinecellval">
          <input type="radio" id="quanlineradio2" value="2" name="quanline" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pricelinewrap">
      <div class="priceline">
        <div class="pricelinecellval">
          <input type="radio" id="quanlineradio3" value="3" name="quanline" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="newquanfield tablecell almiddle">
    <input type="number" min="1" size="2" class="quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="2" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps! :)